# Friend or Friends in this sentence

Tags: nouns, singular

I came across this English sentence when I was reading an article:

> Have you ever met anyone on holiday who you were **friends** with at school or university?

Wasn't it supposed to be "friend" in place of "friends" there?

Comment: The expression is, "to be friends with someone".

Answer (score 8):

*Be friends with* is the ordinary English idiom: it expresses the notion that the friendship is not a relationship from one person to another but exists between two (or more) people.

> John and I were friends.
>   I was friends with John.
>   John was friends with Tom, Amy and Margie.

When you are speaking of just one side of the relationship you may say: *John is a friend **to** Amy* (but that's fairly rare these days, and tends to be used specifically of John's actions on her behalf) or *John is a friend of Amy's*, signifying that he is one of her (many) friends.

Comment: +1. Note that this idiom is specific to *friend* (and close variants such as *best friend*); it's not used with other mutual relationships. For example, we would *not* say \*"Jim is brothers with Mike", or \*"he's enemies with her", or \*"she didn't want to be lovers with him".

Answer (score 7):

Using "were friends with" is correct. The word *friend* gets pluralized when "friends with" alludes to a friendship between you and the other person:

> At Dartmouth, I was best **friends** with Sharon.
>   At the reunion, I met a guy I had been **friends** with back in the 1980s.
>   Why aren't they getting along? Bill used to be good **friends** with Ted.

When you change the wording of the sentence to avoid the phrase "friends *with*", then you'd use the singular:

> Have you ever met anyone on holiday who **had been your friend** at school or university?
>   Why aren't they getting along? Bill used to be Ted's good **friend**.